# MySQL random unable to connect messages

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have an Apache server, that connects to a MySQL database server. I get a lot of error messages saying:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.13'

But most of the time, there's no problem connecting, and I am able to `telnet 10.0.0.13 3306` without problems. How do I figure out what the problem is?

The source is php scripts, and most of the time it runs without any problem.  Here is how I connect:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
date_default_timezone_set ('Europe/Copenhagen');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
$conn = new mysqli('10.0.0.13','webuser', 'xxxxxx', "np_indexes");
```

Any suggestions?

Is this connection closed correct?

```
$sql = "call spGetOrderDepthBySymbol('$stock', 0)";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <row>
            <type static="true"></type>
            <shares flash="true"><?= $row['shares']<>"" ? number_format($row['shares'], 0, ',', '.') : '-' ?></shares>
            <price flash="true"><?= $row['price']<>"" ? number_format($row['price'], 2, ',', '.') : '-' ?></price>
        </row>
    <? }
    ?>
    <spacer static="true"></spacer>
    <? 
    $conn->next_result();
    $sql = "call spGetOrderDepthBySymbol('$stock', 1)";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <row>
            <type static="true"></type>
            <shares flash="true"><?= $row['shares']<>"" ? number_format($row['shares'], 0, ',', '.') : '-' ?></shares>
            <price flash="true"><?= $row['price']<>"" ? number_format($row['price'], 2, ',', '.') : '-' ?></price>
        </row>
    <? } 
    mysql_close($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: Is your mysql running? Perhaps a restart of the mysqld service?

Comment: There could be a connection limit in place.

Comment: Do you remember to close your connection once you're done with it?  Even (especially) when your program errors out early?

Comment: The MySQL is running, 99% of the time, there's no problem. Restarting does not solve this, i have tried that.

Where can i check if there's a connection limit?

Comment: It might be because the connecions is not closed correctly.

Do I close this correct? Added a script to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps this is your case. [see here](http://www.filonov.com/2009/08/07/sqlstatehy000-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-13/)

the solution says:`login as root and do
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`

Comment: I think that if server refuses connection from the network, the error would be persistant and not random.

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL server work on Windows - read this section: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html#can-not-connect-to-server-on-windows

Comment: Both serveres is running linux (Debian)